# sleep to hibernate fails, laptop shuts down

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

An issue i am having with my new windows 10 on lenovo laptop (just now moved from win8.1). When I move the laptop to "sleep" state, its okay for a short time period. But I've noticed that over longer periods of time, when I switch it back on again from sleep - it in fact behaves like it was shut down and restarts fresh, without restoring any open programs.

So far, this is an issue i discovered many people face, and the solution is always "turn hibernate after..." to Never.

But I DO think that hibernate is a good thing - it saves battery, probably also takes off strain from the hard disk drive and more.

So my question is - did some one find out what exactly goes wrong there (sleep->hibernate bug? hibernate->restore "snapshot" bug?) and has a good solution that does not involve turning off the hibernate option?

Comment: I don't understand what issue you're describing, could you be more specific? ([Edit] your question)

Comment: There isn't likely a specific bug causing this, that hasn't been fixed by now. We can't answer the question in this case... we'll need details of your setup etc to be able to advise how to resolve you issue.

Comment: hey @gronostaj and Stese, i edited and recapped. tried not to create another issue that repeats iteself.